# Joomla create template like http://launchrock.com/features

Tags: joomla

http://launchrock.com/features

i want to create a template like http://launchrock.com/features ..

I  would like to know how it is implemented, how to create the sliding effect they have used ?

Comment: which slide effect are you talking about? I don't see one

Answer (score 1):

Well, that site isn't joomla, and to build a template with that complexity with limited knowledge will be a nightmare I would think.

I'd highly recommend using an existing template framework like [RocketTheme](http://www.rockettheme.com/) or another get started with.  [JoomlaXTC](http://joomlaxtc.com/) also some very cool sliding/graphic templates.  You can see there how the libraries and graphics are incorporated into the Joomla framework to get the effect your want.  Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

As said by @GDP, it will be tough creating a template for Joomla. I have been working with Joomla for years and still haven't made a template for Joomla as it require a lot of time, not like your typical CSS template. My recommendations would be as follows:

1. Purchase a template from  a well known company such as Yootheme, Rockettheme, Joomlart etc if you are looking for something heavy, stylish, professional and feature packed.
2. Download a blank template [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/tools/design-tools/18381) ad build it up from scratch if you really have the time.
3. Download a free template and such as the Yootheme Master theme.
4. Use a framework such as YouGrids, T3 or Construct5 to assist

Comment: here is a tutorial to create joomla template from scratch http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/08/create-joomla-template-from-scratch_28.html